# Set vim current working directory to the current project root or to the directory of the current file

Tags: git, vim, mercurial, vim-plugin

How can I (automatically, basically I shouldn't have anything to do apart from initial configuration) set vim cwd to the project root directory (if there's any) or to the current buffer directory (in an `autochdir` fashion)?

Here is an example of a file path to expected cwd: `~/foo/bar/SOME_FILE` -> `~/foo` if there is a `~/foo/.git/` dir or a `~/foo/.hg/` dir otherwise `~/foo/bar/`

I'm aware of [airblade/vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) but it doesn't quite work (e.g. it relies on specific file extensions, and I don't want this behavior).

Comment: `set autochdir` will bring you to current buffer's dir, won't it?

Comment: vim-rooter now runs on all buffers, regardless of file extension, by default.

Comment: If someone is interested in a convenient manual fashion and uses already `vim-fugitive`, he can type `:Gcd` to switch to the root directory of the git repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the vim-rooter plugin with an autocmd to trigger on all files, something like `autocmd BufEnter * :Rooter`.  That's probably the simplest way.

Comment: Oh that works, I had tried the `autocmd rooter BufEnter * :Rooter` recommended in the `README` but that didn't work, but dropping the `rooter` works fine. Thanks.

Comment: `rooter` refered to an example `rooter` filetype script created one step before.